# Eclipse: The project was not built due to error

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I get this error message whenever I create new Spring MVC projects in Eclipse STS.

`The project was not built due to "Error deleting resource '/ProjectName/target/classes/log4j.xml' from the workspace tree." Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent.`

Why is this happening? I haven't changed anything and the file located at `classes\log4j.xml`exist on the file system. When I try to import the files, Eclipse tells me that I can't because the source is already existing in the project (even though it's telling me it has been deleted).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may be because the file/folder is locked and eclipse could not delete it. Try re-starting Eclipse. If that doesn't work, manually delete the files. Since it is in classes folder, it will get re-created when you build.

If all else fails, try restarting the machine.

Comment: I deleted the file on the file system and it gets recreated again (as long as Eclipse is open). I still can't import the `classes` folder because Eclipse believes the folder is in the workspace even though it isn't. Do you have any other suggestions on how to import this `classes` folder into the workspace? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you're requirements are, but classes folder is usually created when the source is built. You don't manually import it. If you're looking to import a jar of some kind, then you should be placing it in the lib folder.

Comment: Thanks for response Vaishak...I'm not trying to build the project. I'm just trying to get the classes folder to show up in the Eclipse workspace. I see it on the file system via Windows Explorer, but Eclipse is throwing an error saying that the folder has been deleted and that I need to add the folder to the workspace then refresh the project to get it back in-sync with the file system. However, when I attempt to import the folder via File > Import > General > File System Eclipse won't let me import the folder because it says that it's already part of the workspace! Does this make sense??

Comment: I don't see why you would want to import the classes folder, but have you tried creating a new workspace and importing it there?